# How long should I wait before turning on a window AC after moving it?

Tags: air-conditioning

So my downstairs AC went, of course during this insane heat wave. Checked out Lowes and found a small room AC for 150$ so came up with a plan. My room AC is rated for a much bigger space so I bought the 150$ one for my room and moved the one there downstairs into the living room. So, I know that oil and that liquid refridgeration stuff needs to settle before I turn it on. Do I really need to wait 24hrs? While moving it I managed to keep it fairly level (not perfect but certainly not more than 45* one way or the other). Thanks for the advice and stay cool today everyone!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Did you look for the manuals for the A/Cs? (They'd likely mention anything like this.)

Comment: I had one that said next to the on/off/temp dial to wait 30 minutes.  But like Daniel said, RTFM.

Comment: I would but I inherited the unit from my aunt so I don't have the manual

Answer (score 1):

If you kept the unit upright the entire time, you shouldn't need to wait at all.  When the unit is turned on its side or upside down, the oil in the compressor can drain out and get stuck in other areas.  Once you turn the unit back over, it takes some time for it to drain back to where it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I was thinking. I have it like an HR or two anyways but it seemed to work just fine and still is do far.